# Is there a way to extract the CSS selector with Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to scrape this (https://www.qconcursos.com/questoes-de-concursos/questoes?discipline_ids%5B%5D=13&discipline_ids%5B%5D=16&discipline_ids%5B%5D=39&discipline_ids%5B%5D=46&discipline_ids%5B%5D=56&discipline_ids%5B%5D=57&examining_board_ids%5B%5D=1&examining_board_ids%5B%5D=2&examining_board_ids%5B%5D=5&page=2&scholarity_ids%5B%5D=1&scholarity_ids%5B%5D=2) webpage. I'm extracting all images on the website. However, they do not contain size (width, height) attributes, so they are extracted with their original one. That being said, the image ends up way too big. This is why I'm extracting the rendered size and adding width and height tag to every single tag.

Example:

`<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.qconcursos-hmg.com/cms/brazil-week/logo.svg">`

has to become

`<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.qconcursos-hmg.com/cms/brazil-week/logo.svg" height="32" width="120">`

I'm able to get all images and the correct size. My problem is: I'm not able to insert the values into the tags.

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
driver.execute_script(f'let element =  document.querySelector("#image_sec>img"); element.setAttribute("width", "{w}"); element.setAttribute("height", "{h}");')
```

So I need the CSS selector to find the element with javascript and set the attributes to the tag.

This is a code you can use to reproduce the problem:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from scrapy.selector import Selector

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.qconcursos.com/questoes-de-concursos/questoes?discipline_ids%5B%5D=13&discipline_ids%5B%5D=16&discipline_ids%5B%5D=39&discipline_ids%5B%5D=46&discipline_ids%5B%5D=56&discipline_ids%5B%5D=57&examining_board_ids%5B%5D=1&examining_board_ids%5B%5D=2&examining_board_ids%5B%5D=5&page=2&scholarity_ids%5B%5D=1&scholarity_ids%5B%5D=2")

while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

    link = driver.current_url

    try:
        images = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//img')
        for img in images:
            size = img.size
            w, h = size['width'], size['height']

        driver.execute_script(f'let element =  document.querySelector("#image_sec>img"); element.setAttribute("width", "{w}"); element.setAttribute("height", "{h}");')

    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
```

Update: I've tried following this solution but no success. [Is there a way to extract the CSS selector with Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69032956/is-there-a-way-to-extract-the-css-selector-with-selenium), there are 2 answers. The first one retrieves the  tags, but doesn't add any attributes. The same for the second one.

Comment: Why can't you use requests or beautifulsoup as mentioned in other questions? Is there any restriction on their usage?

Comment: I edited my answer and added a step-by-step to reproduce the problem in case you want to take a look. I'll give requests and beautifulsoup another try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution. https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/pgp5cg/how_can_i_extract_a_css_selector_of_an_element/hbcydib/?context=3

```
driver.execute_script(f'arguments[0].setAttribute("width", "{w}"); arguments[0].setAttribute("height", "{h}");', img)
```

I'm not very familiar with Javascript so don't quote me on that. But I believe `arguments[0]` is passing my element as `this`, so it's basically telling my code to set a new attribute to my `img` element.

This is the working example

```
try:
    images = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/img')

    for img in images:
        size = img.size
        w, h = size['width'], size['height']

        driver.execute_script(f'arguments[0].setAttribute("width", "{w}"); arguments[0].setAttribute("height", "{h}");', img)
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Sorry. Added an explanation and an example.

Answer (score 0):

This web is protected with Cloudflare and your code doesn't work

Comment: I edited the code and it's working now. I've been scraping this page for a few days.